# What is the major difference between Varchar2 and char

Tags: sql, oracle, char, varchar2

**Creating Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
charcol    CHAR(10),
varcharcol VARCHAR2(10));

SELECT LENGTH(charcol), LENGTH(varcharcol) FROM test;
```

**Result:**

```
LENGTH(CHARCOL) LENGTH(VARCHARCOL)
--------------- ------------------
             10                  1
```

Please Let me know what is the difference between Varchar2 and char?
At what times we use both?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simple example to show the difference:

```
SELECT 
    '"'||CAST('abc' AS VARCHAR2(10))||'"', 
    '"'||CAST('abc' AS CHAR(10))||'"' 
FROM dual;


'"'||CAST('ABC'ASVARCHAR2(10))||'"' '"'||CAST('ABC'ASCHAR(10))||'"'
----------------------------------- -------------------------------
"abc"                               "abc       "                   
1 row selected.
```

The CHAR is usefull for expressions where the length of charaters is always fix, e.g. postal code for US states, for example CA, NY, FL, TX

Comment: CHAR is never really "useful": US state codes are just as efficiently stored as VARCHAR2.

Answer (score 32):

Although there are already several answers correctly describing the behaviour of `char`, I think it needs to be said that **you should not use it** except in three specific situations:

1. You are building a fixed-length file or report, and assigning a non-null value to a `char` avoids the need to code an `rpad()` expression. For example, if `firstname` and `lastname` are both defined as `char(20)`, then `firstname||lastname` is a shorter way of writing `rpad(firstname,20)||rpad(lastname,20)` to create
   `Chuck               Norris`
2. You need to distinguish between the explicit empty string `''` and `null`. Normally they are the same thing in Oracle, but assigning `''` to a `char` value will trigger its blank-padding behaviour while `null` will not, so if it's important to tell the difference, and I can't really think of a reason why it would be, then you have a way to do that.
3. Your code is ported from (or needs to be compatible with) some other system that requires blank-padding for legacy reasons. In that case you are stuck with it and you have my sympathy.

There is really **no reason to use `char`** just because some length is fixed (e.g. a `Y/N` flag or an ISO currency code such as `'USD'`). It's not more efficient, it doesn't save space (there's no mythical length indicator for a `varchar2`, there's just a blank padding overhead for `char`), and it doesn't stop anyone entering shorter values. (If you enter `'ZZ'` in your `char(3)` currency column, it will just get stored as `'ZZ '`.) It's not even backward-compatible with some ancient version of Oracle that once relied on it, because there never was one.

And the contagion can spread, as (following best practice) you might anchor a variable declaration using something like `sales.currency%type`. Now your `l_sale_currency` variable is a stealth `char` which will get invisibly blank-padded for shorter values (or `''`), opening the door to obscure bugs where `l_sale_currency` does not equal `l_refund_currency` even though you assigned `'ZZ'` to both of them.

Some argue that `char(n)` (where *n* is some character length) indicates that values are expected to be *n* characters long, and this is a form of self-documentation. But surely if you are serious about a 3-character format ([ISO-Alpha-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3) country codes rather than [ISO-Alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2), for example), wouldn't you define a constraint to enforce the rule, rather than letting developers glance at a `char(3)` datatype and draw their own conclusions?

`CHAR` was introduced in Oracle 6 for, I'm sure, ANSI compatibility reasons. Probably there are potential customers deciding which database product to purchase and *ANSI compatibility* is on their checklist (or used to be back then), and `CHAR` with blank-padding is defined in the ANSI standard, so Oracle needs to provide it. You are not supposed to actually use it.

Comment: This should be the top answer - especially for "You are not supposed to actually use it"!

Comment: +1 because your explanation matches with a couple of Tom Kyte's post on asktom.oracle.com: [Char Vs Varchar](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2668391900346844476) and [Shoud I use char or varchar2](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:123212348063,)

Answer (score 7):

Just to avoid confusion about much wrong information. Here are some information about difference including performance

Reference: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2668391900346844476

> Since a char is nothing more than a VARCHAR2 that is blank padded out
>   to the maximum length - that is, the difference between the columns X
>   and Y below:
>
> create table t ( x varchar2(30), y char(30) );  insert into t (x,y)
>   values ( rpad('a',' ',30), 'a' );
>
> IS ABSOLUTELY NOTHING, and given that the difference between columns X
>   and Y below:
>
> insert into t (x,y) values ('a','a')
>
> is that X consumes 3 bytes (null indicator, leading byte length, 1
>   byte for 'a') and Y consumes 32 bytes (null indicator, leading byte
>   length, 30 bytes for 'a ' )
>
> Umm, varchar2 is going to be somewhat "at an advantage performance
>   wise". It helps us NOT AT ALL that char(30) is always 30 bytes - to
>   us, it is simply a varchar2 that is blank padded out to the maximum
>   length. It helps us in processing - ZERO, zilch, zippo.
>
> Anytime you see anyone say "it is up to 50% faster", and that is it -
>   no example, no science, no facts, no story to back it up - just laugh
>   out loud at them and keep on moving along.
>
> There are other "made up things" on that page as well, for example:
>
> > *"Searching is faster in CHAR as all the strings are stored at a*
> >     *specified position from the each other, the system doesnot have to*
> >     *search for the end of string.  Whereas in VARCHAR the system has to*
> >     *first find the end of string and then go for searching."*
>
> FALSE: a char is just a varchar2 blank padded - we do not store
>   strings "at a specified position from each other". We do search for
>   the end of the string - we use a leading byte length to figure things
>   out.

Answer (score 4):

**CHAR** type has fixed size, so if you say it is 10 bytes, then it always stores 10 bytes in the database and it doesn't matter whether you store any text or just empty 10 bytes

**VARCHAR2** size depends on how many bytes you are actually going to store in the database. The number you specify is just the maximum number of bytes that can be stored (although 1 byte is minimum)

You should use CHAR when dealing with fixed length strings (you know in advance the exact length of string you will be storing) - database can then manipulate with it better and faster since it knows the exact lenght

You should use VARCHAR2 when you don't know the exact lenght of stored strings.

Situation you would use both may be:

```
name VARCHAR2(255),
zip_code CHAR(5) --if your users have only 5 place zip codes
```

Comment: In both which one is better to use?

Comment: @ram:- I dont think anyone can say that which one is better without knowing the requirement because one may be better than the other base on the requirement!

Answer (score 4):

**CHAR**

CHAR should be used for storing fix length character strings. String values will be space/blank padded before stored on disk. If this type is used to store varibale length strings, it will waste a lot of disk space.

**VARCHAR2**

VARCHAR2 is used to store variable length character strings. The string value's length will be stored on disk with the value itself.

**And**

```
At what times we use both?
```

Its all depend upon your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

When stored in a database, varchar2 uses only the allocated space. E.g. if you have a varchar2(1999) and put 50 bytes in the table, it will use 52 bytes.

But when stored in a database, char always uses the maximum length and is blank-padded. E.g. if you have char(1999) and put 50 bytes in the table, it will consume 2000 bytes.

Answer (score -2):

**CHAR** is used for storing fix length character strings.  It will waste a lot of disk space if this type is used to store varibale length strings.

**VARCHAR2** is used to store variable length character strings.

> At what times we use both?

This may vary and depend on your requirement.

**EDIT:-**

Lets understand this with an example, If you have an student name column with size 10; sname `CHAR(10)` and If a column value `'RAMA'` is inserted, **6 empty spaces** will be inserted to the right of the value. If this was a VARCHAR column; sname `VARCHAR2(10).` Then Varchar will take 4 spaces out of 10 possible and free the next 6 for other usage.

Comment: Mostly in which situation we use both?

Comment: @ram: Lets understand this with an example, If you have an student name column with size 10; sname CHAR(10) and If a column value 'RAMA' is inserted, 6 empty spaces will be inserted to the right of the value. If this was a VARCHAR column; sname VARCHAR2(10). Then Varchar will take 4 spaces out of 10 possible and free the next 6 for other usage.

Comment: 6 for other usage  means?

Comment: @ram:- 6 for other usage means that the leftover memory can be utilized by some other value  :)