# Difference of CHAR and VARCHAR2 in an Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named tab1 with a column as col1 and data type as varchar2(10) and another table named tab2 with a single column as col2 and data type as char(20)

with following data:

```
tab1    tab2
a        a
b        b
c        c
```

when I run the following query

```
select tab1.*,tab2.*
from tab1 full join tab2
on tab1.col1 = tab2.col2;
```

I get the following output:

```
col1   col2
null   a
null   b
null   c
a      null
b      null
c      null
```

I know that char occupies fixed memory but should oracle not join on string comparison?

Comment: Very good and long explanation of the top answers below [here at this site](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2668391900346844476)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417845/what-is-the-major-difference-between-varchar2-and-char/20418849#20418849

Answer (score 4):

`varchar2(10)` occupied only required space.

`char(20)` will pad blank at end if the text is of smaller length.

Hence, in tab1 col1, value `a` is stored as `a`
but in tab2 col2, value `a` is stored as `a`                   
and hence no match.

Answer (score 2):

Char is blank padded to its full width, so you are comparing

```
'a                   ' with 'a'
```

and they are not the same

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the Oracle Documentation...

https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.htm#SQLRF30027

**Blank-Padded and Nonpadded Comparison Semantics**

> With blank-padded semantics, if the two values have different lengths,
>   then Oracle first adds blanks to the end of the shorter one so their
>   lengths are equal. Oracle then compares the values character by
>   character up to the first character that differs. The value with the
>   greater character in the first differing position is considered
>   greater. If two values have no differing characters, then they are
>   considered equal. This rule means that two values are equal if they
>   differ only in the number of trailing blanks. Oracle uses blank-padded
>   comparison semantics only when both values in the comparison are
>   either expressions of data type CHAR, NCHAR, text literals, or values
>   returned by the USER function.
>
> With nonpadded semantics, Oracle compares two values character by
>   character up to the first character that differs. The value with the
>   greater character in that position is considered greater. If two
>   values of different length are identical up to the end of the shorter
>   one, then the longer value is considered greater. If two values of
>   equal length have no differing characters, then the values are
>   considered equal. Oracle uses nonpadded comparison semantics whenever
>   one or both values in the comparison have the data type VARCHAR2 or
>   NVARCHAR2.
>
> The results of comparing two character values using different
>   comparison semantics may vary. The table that follows shows the
>   results of comparing five pairs of character values using each
>   comparison semantic. Usually, the results of blank-padded and
>   nonpadded comparisons are the same. The last comparison in the table
>   illustrates the differences between the blank-padded and nonpadded
>   comparison semantics.

Comment: @Boneist Link Added

Answer (score 0):

Edit: After reading the other answers, you can know what is wrong. You can overcome it by using below syntax.

```
select tab1.*,tab2.*
from tab1 full join tab2
on trim(tab1.col1)=trim(tab2.col2);
```

Comment: No need to down vote on this answer ,it is not elaborate thats it!!

Comment: Thanks mate. Anyways I got to learn the `char padding` stuff today which I wasn't aware of.