# Inserting DECIMAL type to Oracle DB with SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, rounding

Friends, i'm new in SQL and i can't find answer to my question

I'm trying to insert decimal number with SQL Developer (version 4, build 15), but SQL Developer automaticaly rounding my number. My test DB is OracleXE112_Win64.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE salespeople
  (
    snum  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    sname CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    city  CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    comm  DECIMAL
  );
```

then

```
insert into SALESPEOPLE 
values (1001, 'Peel', 'London', .12);
insert into SALESPEOPLE 
values (1002, 'Serres', 'San Jose', .13);
insert into SALESPEOPLE 
values (1004, 'Motika', 'London', .11);
insert into SALESPEOPLE 
values (1007, 'Rifkin', 'Barcelona', .15);
insert into SALESPEOPLE 
values (1003, 'Axelrod', 'New York', .10);
```

As as result i see **0** in **comm** column.
When i'm trying to insert number **1.35**, it's rounding to 1.

Thanks

Comment: The scale defaults to 0 for DECIMAL, which means that DECIMAL(*) is treated as NUMBER(*, 0), i.e. INTEGER

Comment: I don't think `CHAR(15)` is the proper data type for `sname` and `city`, see [What is the major difference between VARCHAR2 and CHAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417845/what-is-the-major-difference-between-varchar2-and-char/20418849)

Comment: If you are new to Oracle SQL then I suggest some basic reading (it wont take long), a starter is https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements.htm.

Answer (score 1):

The `decimal` data type needs a scale and precision.  "Scale" is the number of digits after the decimal point.

When you don't specify the value for scale, then it defaults to 0 -- essentially an integer.  (And precision defaults to 5.)

Typically, Oracle databases use `number` instead of `decimal`.  But, if you want `decimal`, specify the appropriate scale and precision.

Comment: Following up on Gordon's excellent answer - my recommendation, based on years of bitterly hard-won experience, is that the default numeric type to use in Oracle is NUMBER. Other numeric types, or even NUMBER with precision and/or scale specified, should only be used in situations with very unusual requirements. YMMV.

Comment: Adding my voice to this - agreeing with both Gordon and Bob. There is no reason I can think of to use DECIMAL over NUMBER. Especially since NUMBER is specifically a "decimal" numeric type (where division by 25 is 100% accurate, unlike any binary data type where it can't be).

Comment: Thank you very much! For learning i'm using old book by Martin Gruber. He used DECIMAL very often. Now i will use NUMBER type for this column.

Comment: @Kos - excellent! Be advised that what you will read in the book will often be different from what you find in the real world (but often the difference will be small, especially if you "know what to do" - as will be the case now with DECIMAL vs. NUMBER). In the future, feel free to post questions here, just like you did, showing what you expected and what happened. It always helps to state that you are learning from the book, and the book says x but you found y. That will help people give you better answers, knowing the background.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the Oracle documentation for [**DECIMAL**](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj15260.html), it says:

"If the scale is not specified, the default scale is 0. If the precision is not specified, the default precision is 5."

**Precision** is : "the total number of digits, both to the left and the right of the decimal point".

**Scale** is : "the number of digits of the fractional component".

This means that because your default scale is 0, then all numbers are rounded to an integer.

To fix this you need to specify a `SCALE` for your data. Most scenarios I've seen are sufficed by `DECIMAL(18,5)` and from your example queries this should be fine.

So, just change your table definition to:

```
CREATE TABLE salespeople
  (
    snum  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    sname CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    city  CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    comm  DECIMAL(18,5)
  );
```

Comment: @Karthik Not really the point of this question / answer. Maybe OP actually requires this.

Comment: Thank you very much! For learning i'm using old book by Martin Gruber. He used DECIMAL very often. Now i will use NUMBER type for this column.