# Update record based on primary key composite with Timestamp type

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm stuck on a hard and tricky problem with updating a record from timestamp data.

*Technologies :*

- Spring and Java
- Hibernate and JPA
- Oracle Databse for version 11g

Create SQL Script for the table :

```
CREATE TABLE DOSSIER(
  NUM_DOSS NUMBER NOT NULL,
  TYPE_DOSS CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  DATE_DOSS TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
  DSC_DOSS VARCHAR(25),
  NUM_CNFR VARCHAR(25),
  TMS_CREA TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
  TMS_MAJ TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_TDECL_RMGV PRIMARY KEY(NUM_DOSS, TYPE_DOSS, DATE_DOSS)
);
```

Here's my SQL request for updating :

```
UPDATE DOSSIER
    SET
        NUM_CNFR='999'
    WHERE
        NUM_DOSS_='2006103009564900' 
        and TYP_DOSS='011' 
        and DATE_DOSS= TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-08-09 16:57:03.786586', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6')
```

You should know that records can have same folder number and type but never the same date because it's a timestamp with milliseconds.

For example :

```
NUM_DOSS           TYP_DOSS   DATE_DOSS                    NUM_CNFR
2006103009564900   | 011      | 2017-08-09 16:57:03.786586 | null
2006103009564900   | 011      | 2017-08-09 16:57:03.786589 | 0125
```

My DossierEntityPK class :

```
@Embeddable
public class DossierEntityPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4418929855229352729L;

    @Column(name = "NUM_DOSS", nullable = false)
    private String numDossier;

    @Column(name = "TYPE_DOSS", nullable = false)
    private String typeDossier;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "DATE_DOSS", updatable = false, nullable = false,  columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT")
    private Date dateDossier;
}
```

My DossierEntity class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TDECL_RMGV")
public class OERemiseGouvModele {

    @EmbeddedId
    private DossierEntityPK dossierEntityPK;

    @Column(name = "DSC_DOSS", nullable = true)
    private String descriptionDossier;

    @Column(name = "NUM_CNFR", nullable = true)
    private String numConfirmation;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "TMS_CREA", nullable = false)
    private Date tmsCreation;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "TMS_MAJ", nullable = false)
    private Date tmsMaj;
}
```

I will show you now my query in JPQL :

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE DossierEntity d SET d.numConfirmation=:numConfirmation WHERE d.dossierEntityPK.numDossier=:numDossierAND d.dossierEntityPK.typeDossier=:typeDossier AND d.dossierEntityPK.dateDossier= TO_TIMESTAMP(:dateDossier, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6')")
int updateFolder(@Param("numConfirmation") String numConfirmation, @Param("numDossier") String numDossier, @Param("typeDossier") String typeDossier, @Param("dateDossier") Date dateDossier);
```

Then when I execute this method from my web application, there is a empty result from Hibernate. But if I execute this SQL request Update directly on my database, it works well !

I even execute this SQL request with JDBC or with PreparedStatement but I get the same empty result then no record is updated.

I already know this is not a very good idea to use a timestamp in clause WHERE but the workflow works in this way and I can't change that the timestamp is unique and is in a part of composite primary key with folder number and type.

Do you have an idea about how to fix it ?

Comment: Don't know why you said is bad idea use timestamp in `WHERE` ? As you already said the query direct on the DB work OK. Did you try remove the timestamp condition for the `WHERE` and see if you can get any result (of course test if is a developer db).

Comment: It's a bad idea because to execute an update query or delete query, it should be based on identity number only but in my case I can't use only the identity of folder. Yes I did and I don't have any result using only folder number and type for the WHERE condition

Comment: Can you change `TYPE_DOSS CHAR(4)` into `TYPE_DOSS VARCHAR(4)`? If not, you need to pad the three-character input you're passing in.

Comment: most likely Hibernate convert your Date object using current timezone offset, make sure you are running JVM with -Duser.timezone=GMT flag

Comment: The Oracle type for short strings is `varchar2`. [Don't use `char`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165653/230471)

Comment: @MickMnemonic thank you so much ! I was so blinded by the timestamp type that I didn't see my mistake about the column TYPE_DOSS ! Indeed, if the type is a char and you insert only 3 characters into this column, then it will have 3 strings and an space. For example : "CAR" will be in database like "CAR ".

Answer (score 0):

Executing this SQL request with JDBC or with PreparedStatement, the records are updated and works fine

Comment: Yes I already executed my SQL request with JDBC or with PreparedStatement but same result. Anyway I found the solution thanks to @MickMnemonic :)