# Is there boolean type for column in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to:

```
select 1>2 from dual;
```

but got:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Is there boolean type for column expression in Oracle SQL?

I able to do:

```
select case when 1>2 then 'T' else 'F' end from dual;
```

Originally I tried to compare date fields and the quickest way I found was getting difference and look to sign...

**UPDATE** I tried `SIGN` function, I don't know if it is vendor specific extension:

```
select SIGN(1-2) from dual;
select SIGN(DATE '2017-01-02' - DATE '2017-02-12') from dual;
```

but this trick doesn't work for strings...

Comment: No, there is not a boolean type.  You can use a `char()` or small integer.

Comment: char(1) with 1 and 0 would be your best bet.

Comment: I am looking for a way to express result of comparing of two values. I am not interested in creating column with "boolean" type.

Comment: [`sign`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html) returns -1, 0 or 1 (or null) according to the sign of the operand. You could use `case` to test string values. Column datatypes are listed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html). Avoid [`char`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165653/230471) at all costs.

Answer (score 4):

No there is not, you can use 0 and 1 just as yes/no.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to get the result 1 if something is true and 0 if it is false, you can use a `case` expression:

```
select case when (any_logical_condition_here) then 1 else 0 end as my_col
from   ....
where  ....
```

For example:

```
select case when 1 > 2 then 1 else 0 end as bool_result
from   dual;

                            BOOL_RESULT
---------------------------------------
                                      0
```

**NOTE** though - "Boolean" refers strictly to the `TRUE/FALSE` logic, it has no place for `UNKNOWN`. When you deal with `null`, as you must in SQL, you need three-valued logic. The `case` expression as written above returns `1` when the logical condition is `true` and `0` otherwise. Try it with `1 > null` - the truth value is `UNKNOWN`, the `case` expression will return 0.

Comment: As is well-established in lore, Boolean is indeed trivalent: [`True`, `False`, `FileNotFound` (link)](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_)