# SELECT Values from Varray ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, varray

I am using apex.oracle and the error I get is `[unsupported data type]`. 
The explanation: I have a table named Playlist and I want to store an array of songs into the `Songs` field. For this reason I've defined a type named `PlaylistSongs` of `varray` of `chars`. The insertion works, but when I do the SELECT, I get `[unsupported data type]` instead of my array with values.

Here is the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PlaylistSongs AS VARRAY(4) OF CHAR(16);

CREATE TABLE PLAYLIST (
    IDPlaylist              NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    PlaylistName            CHAR(64),
    PlaylistAuthor          NUMBER(2),
    PlaylistDuration        NUMBER,
    ActivePlaylist          NUMBER(1),
    Songs                   PlaylistSongs,

    CONSTRAINT PLAYLIST_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (IDPlaylist),
    CONSTRAINT PLAYLIST_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KEY (PlaylistAuthor) REFERENCES DJ (IDDJ)
);

INSERT INTO PLAYLIST VALUES (1, 'Rap', 1, 153, 1, 1, PlaylistSongs('River', 'Lose Yourself', 'Till I Collapse', 'Walk On Water'));
```

After a bit of research, I've found the `TABLE` operator.

```
SELECT *
FROM PLAYLIST p, TABLE(p.Songs) ps
```

This works but instead of displaying the array as a regular array, it displays each entry on a new row.

[image]

I need it to look like `['River', 'Lose Yourself', 'Till I Collapse', 'Walk On Water']`. Can it be done?

Comment: Yes - see [`listagg()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm). Also, use `varchar2` for strings, not `char` which applies blank-padding you don't need (actually, nobody needs it - `char` is for portability and ANSI completeness only and is not meant for use in new development).

Comment: You are the hero. Thank you!

Here is the solution just in case someone will need it:

`SELECT PlaylistName, LISTAGG(column_value, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column_value) as "Playlist"
FROM Playlist, TABLE(Songs)
GROUP BY PlaylistName`

Comment: Thanks - I've made my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - see the [`listagg()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm) aggregate function (goes with a `group by` clause):

```
select idplaylist
     , playlistname
     , playlistauthor
     , playlistduration
     , activeplaylist
     , listagg(rtrim(ps.column_value), ', ') within group (order by ps.column_value) as songs
from   playlist p
       cross join table(p.songs) ps
group by
       idplaylist
     , playlistname
     , playlistauthor
     , playlistduration
     , activeplaylist;
```

Also, [use `varchar2` for strings, not `char`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165653/230471) which just applies blank-padding you don't need (actually, nobody needs it - char is for portability and ANSI completeness only and is not meant for use in new development. With a `varchar2` array you won't need the `rtrim()`.