# SQL Foreign Key invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I want to create these two tables in apex.oracle but the foreign key doesn't work. I get this error:

> ORA-00904: "CNP": invalid identifier.

Can you please tell what is the problem? Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE CERCETATOR
(
    CNP CHAR(13) CONSTRAINT PK_CERCETATOR PRIMARY KEY,
    VARSTA NUMBER(2),
    TELEFON NUMBER(12),
    EXPERIENTA NUMBER(2)
)

CREATE TABLE ECHIPAMENT
(
    COD_ECH NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT PK_ECH PRIMARY KEY,
    MARIME VARCHAR2(2),
    CULOARE VARCHAR2(10),
    MATERIAL VARCHAR2(20),
    PRET NUMBER(3,2),

    CONSTRAINT FK_CERCETATOR 
        FOREIGN KEY (CNP) REFERENCES CERCETATOR(CNP)
)
```

Comment: Do you see a column called `CNP` in the definition of `ECHIPAMENT`? Because I don't. And neither does the Oracle compiler, which is why it throws the ORA-00904 error.

Comment: By the way, `CERCETATOR.CNP` should almost certainly be `VARCHAR2(13)` not `CHAR(13)`. `VARCHAR2` is the standard string type in Oracle. `CHAR` is provided for portability and ANSI compatibility but is [rarely what you actually need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165653/230471).

Answer (score -1):

This is your issue.

```
CONSTRAINT FK_CERCETATOR FOREIGN KEY (CNP) REFERENCES CERCETATOR(CNP)
```

in this statement, when you are creating `FOREIGN KEY (CNP)` there is no CNP in ECHIPAYMENT.

Comment: There isn’t a field with the right data type; so the CNP column needs to be added, rather one of the existing columns being used fo the constraint.

Comment: Tables have columns, not fields.

Comment: I am not here to debate proper usage of word column vs field...here is Wikipedia for you. “The word 'field' is normally used interchangeably with 'column'.”