# Displaying Oracle SQL Types

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, types

I am having a hard time getting an output from a table.

Here is the table creation

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE FULL_MAILING_ADDRESS AS OBJECT 
( STREET VARCHAR2(80),
  CITY   VARCHAR2(80),
  STATE  CHAR(2),
  ZIP    VARCHAR2(10));

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 
     (
        FULL_ADDRESS    FULL_MAILING_ADDRESS
     );

  INSERT INTO CUSTOMER  VALUES (FULL_MAILING_ADDRESS('55 SOUTH','ARLINGTON','VA','2222'));
```

when I do select on the table I don't get the values instead I get

```
[ORACLE.FULL_MAILING_ADDRESS]
```

Comment: What do you like to get instead?

Comment: `select * ...` depends on client application you use, but You can simply quote columns you want to see: `select c.full_address.street, c.full_address.city from customer c`.

Comment: By the way, I know I'm always on about this but [`CHAR` isn't as useful as you think it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165653/230471). You should use `VARCHAR2` for all string columns unless they need to be `CLOB`.

Comment: How do i display all the values without specifying a specific one? I was to fetch everything from the table.

Comment: Another possibility is `select XMLTYPE(FULL_ADDRESS) from customer`

Comment: As @PonderStibbons mentioned, the behavior of `select *` will depend on your IDE. If it isn't doing what you want with the object type column, then you can switch to another. If switching to another IDE isn't an option, then you need to list all the fields which you want to see by name in you select list..