# Right Parenthesis Error?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table sales_order(
    order_no varchar2(6) Primary Key check(order_no like 'O%'),
    order_date date,
    client_no varchar2(6) foreign key references client_master(client_no),
    dely_address varchar2(25),
    salesman_no varchar2(6) foreign key references salesman_master(salesman_no),
    dely_type char(1) default 'F' check(dely_type like 'F' OR dely_type like 'P'),
    billed_yn char(1),
    dely_date date check (dely_date > order_date),
    order_status varchar2(10) check(order_status IN ('In Process','Fulfilled','BackOrder','Cancelled'))
);
```

When I am trying to execute this query it displays

> **ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis**. Don't know where right parenthesis is missing.

Comment: That is the default error message when Oracle has no idea what is wrong. :-)

Comment: There is one simple solution. Comment all lines and uncomment one by one until you get error. Then fix it and do it until you get entire table definition.

Comment: Is each occurance of varchar2 meant to be varchar ?

Comment: This table definition has multiple flaws. Anyway working **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=31cef3d233a65881307bb65846666acd)** (removing `foreign key` when you use inline syntax without explicit name)

Comment: Unrelated, but: `check(dely_type like 'F' OR dely_type like 'P')` can be simplified to `check(dely_type in ('F', 'P'))`

Comment: Unrelated, but those `char` columns should be `varchar2` which is the standard string type in Oracle. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165653/230471

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query that has three constraints moved to the end:

```
    create table sales_order(
    order_no varchar2(6) Primary Key check(order_no like 'O%'),
    order_date date,
    client_no varchar2(6) ,
    dely_address varchar2(25),
    salesman_no varchar2(6) ,
    dely_type char(1) default 'F' check(dely_type like 'F' OR dely_type like 'P'),
    billed_yn char(1),
    dely_date date,
    order_status varchar2(10) check(order_status IN ('In Process','Fulfilled','BackOrder','Cancelled')),
    constraint sales_fk foreign key(client_no) references client_master(client_no),
    constraint salesman_fk foreign key(salesman_no) references salesman_master(salesman_no),
    constraint dely_date_ck check (dely_date > order_date)
);
```

Comment: If you move FK definitions to the end, you have to define datatypes for the FK columns. In my opinion it is better practice to let them inherit from the parent.