# Where is the wrong logic in my Create Table statements?

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key, create-table, composite-primary-key

I'm trying to run these statements and I get an error saying `no matching unique or primary key for this column-list`. Can you please help me how to fix this problem?

I get the problem when I try to create table SITE:

```
CREATE TABLE OLMP_COUNTRY (
NOC CHAR(3),
TEAM VARCHAR2(100),
CITY VARCHAR2(100),
CONSTRAINT country_pk PRIMARY KEY(NOC)
);

CREATE TABLE ATHLETE (
ATHELTE_ID CHAR(8),
NAME VARCHAR2(100),
AGE CHAR(3),
SEX CHAR(1),
HEIGHT CHAR(3), 
WEIGHT DECIMAL(3,1), 
NOC CHAR(3), 
CONSTRAINT athlete_pk PRIMARY KEY(ATHLETE_ID), 
CONSTRAINT country_fk FOREIGN KEY(NOC) REFERENCES OLMP_COUNTRY(NOC) 
); 

CREATE TABLE SITE (
NOC CHAR(3),
CITY VARCHAR2(100),
SEASON VARCHAR2(20),
YEAR CHAR(4),
CONSTRAINT site_pk PRIMARY KEY(NOC),
CONSTRAINT country_fk FOREIGN KEY(CITY) REFERENCES OLMP_COUNTRY(CITY)
);

CREATE TABLE RESULTS (
RESULT_ID CHAR(8),
MEDAL CHAR(6),
ATHLETE_ID CHAR(8),
SPORT_EVENT VARCHAR2(100), 
YEAR CHAR(4), 
GAMES VARCHAR2(50), 
CONSTRAINT results_pk PRIMARY KEY(RESULTS_ID) 
);

CREATE TABLE EVENT (
SPORT_EVENT VARCHAR2(100), 
SPORT VARCHAR2(50),
GAMES VARCHAR2(50) 
CONSTRAINT event_pk PRIMARY KEY(SPORT_EVENT)
);
```

Comment: What did you learn reading all answers of many questions found googling your error message, and the manual re FKs? [ask]

Comment: By the way, the standard type for strings in Oracle is `VARCHAR2`. You should only use the highly specialised [`CHAR`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20417845/230471) type in the case where you want to add blank spaces up to the specified length, which is to say, never.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A foreign key should be referencing the primary key of the table it is referring to.

So I think you want:

```
CREATE TABLE SITE (
    NOC CHAR(3),
    CITY VARCHAR2(100),
    SEASON VARCHAR2(20),
    YEAR CHAR(4),
    CONSTRAINT site_pk PRIMARY KEY(NOC),
    CONSTRAINT site_country_fk FOREIGN KEY(NOC) REFERENCES OLMP_COUNTRY(NOC)
);
```

I have no idea why you are repeating `CITY` in both tables, but the foreign key constraint should be to the primary key.  You can look up the city using `JOIN`.  It should not be repeated.

Comment: "...referencing the primary key of the table..." -- For completeness I would add: ...or a column with a `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: I actually got that answer from someone else helping me on another site.. Now it makes sense. Also I ran the updated statement and it says name is already used by an existing constraint? So do I have to just rename the country_fk?

Comment: @Impaler . . . I'm not trying to complete.  I'm trying to give good advice on how databases are created.  They key reference should be to a primary key.

Comment: *"and it says name is already used by an existing constraint? "* - yes, you've already used it on ATHLETE table. This is what a common convention for naming foreign keys is to use the child table and parent table; e.g. `athlete_country_fk`, 'site_country_fk`