# is there a better way to write avg procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I wrote this procedure but it keeps showing "WARNING: Procedure creates with compilation errors" and I don't know why, here's the table I created

```
create table EnrolledInClasses (
    St_Id char(9) primary key, 
    C_Id char(6),
    GradeN Number(2),
    constraint FK_StId Foreign key (St_Id) references Student (St_Id),
    constraint FK_CoID Foreign key (C_Id) references course (C_Id)
    constraint CheckGrade check (Grade>-1)
);
```

and here's the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Avg_grades
IS
    avg_grades NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT AVG (Grade)
    INTO avg_grades
    FROM EnrolledInClasses

    dbms_output.put_line('The average of grades is :'||avg_grades);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('No Data Is Found..');
END;
/
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are quite different.

Comment: It is tagged with plsqldeveloper, so I guess Oracle...? But the compilation error should usually have more info - search for that, it will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Your posted code is missing a semi-colon at the end of the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/), make sure you are writing your code in a Procedure window. Then the compilation error will be clearly highlighted. In this case it's the missing semicolon at the end of the `select into` statement.

[image: []

Or in SQL*Plus you can use `show errors`:

```
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PROCEDURE AVG_GRADES:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
9/12     PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

or the [full syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SHOW.html), `show errors procedure avg_grades`.

Or you can directly query `dba|all|cdb|user_errors`:

```
select * from user_errors e
where  e.name = 'AVG_GRADES'
and    e.attribute = 'ERROR';
```

Also, the table definition could be written more succinctly as:

```
create table enrolledinclasses
( st_id   primary key  constraint fk_stid references student(st_id)
, c_id    constraint   fk_coid references course (c_id)
, grade   number(2)    constraint checkgrade check (grade>-1)
);
```

`student.st_id` and `course.c_id` should probably be numbers or integers, or at least `varchar2`, and [not `char`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165653/230471).

It is good practice to use [code indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) to align code into blocks showing their dependency structure. That would give something like this:

```
create or replace procedure avg_grades as
    avg_grades number := 0;
begin
    select avg(grade) into avg_grades
    from   enrolledinclasses;

    dbms_output.put_line('The average grade is: ' || avg_grades);
exception
    when no_data_found then
        dbms_output.put_line('No Data Is Found.');
end;
```

You might want to `round()` that average before displaying it, as by default it could be displayed with a lot more decimal places than you might want.

Also, it's not possible to get a `no_data_found` exception from a single-group aggregate query like this. If there are no rows in the table you will get a null value as the result, not an error.