# I'm getting "Invalid Identifier Error" for one of my Oracle Apex Queries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to run a script on Oracle Apex and so far all the tables and queries work except the last one. It returns the error "ORA-00904: : invalid identifier ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 626 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658 ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 612 ORA-06512: at "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1749." What should I do to fix this error?

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
     VIN            VARCHAR2(17)
                    CONSTRAINT vehicles__VIN__fk
                      REFERENCES vehicles (VIN) ON DELETE SET NULL,
     sale_date      DATE
                    CONSTRAINT sales__sale_date__fk 
                      REFERENCES sales (sale_date) ON DELETE SET NULL,
     c_name         VARCHAR2(50)
                    CONSTRAINT sales__c_name__nn NOT NULL,
     address        VARCHAR2(50)
                    CONSTRAINT sales__address__nn NOT NULL,
     phone          VARCHAR2(11)
                    CONSTRAINT sales__phone__nn NOT NULL,
     gender         VARCHAR2(6)
                    CONSTRAINT sales__gender__nn NOT NULL,
     a_income       VARCHAR2(30)
                    CONSTRAINT sales__a_income__nn NOT NULL,
    );
```

I don't know if it helps but VIN and sale_date reference these two working queries:

```
CREATE TABLE vehicles(
  VIN   VARCHAR2(17)
        CONSTRAINT vehicles__VIN__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  brand VARCHAR2(20)
        CONSTRAINT vehicles__brand__nn NOT NULL,
  model VARCHAR2(20)
        CONSTRAINT vehicles__model__nn NOT NULL,
  color VARCHAR2(10)
        CONSTRAINT vehicles__color__nn NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE sales(
     sale_date      DATE, 
     price          VARCHAR2(30)
                    CONSTRAINT sales__price__nn NOT NULL,
     VIN            VARCHAR2(17)
                    CONSTRAINT vehicles__VIN__fk
                        REFERENCES vehicles (VIN) ON DELETE SET NULL,
     d_id           VARCHAR2(10)
                     CONSTRAINT dealer__d_id__fk 
                      REFERENCES dealer (d_id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT sales__sale_date__pk PRIMARY KEY (sale_date)
    );
```

Comment: You expect us to tell you what is wrong with a query when you don't show us the query? Can _you_ debug what you cannot see? As for your design - why is GENDER 6 chars when you only need 1 (m/f).  Why is a_income a varchar when it should be a number?  There is really nothing gained by naming Not Null constraints.  very uncommon to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last comma.

Also, if your constraints have the naming convention `<tablename>__<columnname>__<constrainttype>` then don't just copy/paste from another table and update the column name; you need to update the table name as well or you will find you have duplicate constraint names which will raise an exception.

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer(
     VIN            VARCHAR2(17)
                    CONSTRAINT customer__VIN__fk
                      REFERENCES vehicles (VIN) ON DELETE SET NULL,
     sale_date      DATE
                    CONSTRAINT customer__sale_date__fk 
                      REFERENCES sales (sale_date) ON DELETE SET NULL,
     c_name         VARCHAR2(50)
                    CONSTRAINT customer__c_name__nn NOT NULL,
     address        VARCHAR2(500)
                    CONSTRAINT customer__address__nn NOT NULL,
     phone          VARCHAR2(11)
                    CONSTRAINT customer__phone__nn NOT NULL,
     gender         CHAR(1)
                    CONSTRAINT customer__gender__nn NOT NULL
                    CONSTRAINT customer__gender__chk
                      CHECK ( gender IN ( 'M', 'F' /*, 'A', 'B', 'C'*/ ) ),
     a_income       NUMBER(12,2)
                    CONSTRAINT customer__a_income__nn NOT NULL
);
```

Then comes the other questions:

- Why does a customer have a `VIN` (vehicle identification number)? A customer is not limited to owning a single car.
- Why does a customer have a `sale_date`? If you are referring to a car sale then why is the customer limited to a single sale? You probably want to fix both these two by moving the data to a separate table called `customer_cars` (or something similar) so that each customer can own multiple cars and each car can be owned by multiple customers (at different times).
- Do you expect all customers' addresses to fit in 50 characters?
- Why is `gender` a `VARCHAR(6)` and not a `CHAR(1)` with values `M`/`F` (extend with additional character codes as appropriate)?
- Why is `a_income` a string and not a `NUMBER`?

Comment: Surely `varchar2(1)` is a better choice of datatype than `char(1)`? [(Pet peeve alert.)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165653/230471) Anyway, maybe the OP  wants to include non-binary genders.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson There is a semantic difference. `CHAR` is that you want a fixed-length string; `VARCHAR2` is that you want a variable-length string. In this case the data is a fixed-length string so semantically a `CHAR` is appropriate. However, if you are used to people miss-using `CHAR` and want a simple rule to say "just use `VARCHAR2` for everything" then that is fine.

Comment: As for non-binary genders, that is covered in my answer when I say "(extend with additional character codes as appropriate)" and have commented out potential additional check conditions in the code.