# SQL Developer fills remaining space in char with spaces

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a attribute with the data type char(256). I import the value via SQL Developer from a csv file
When the attribute gets a value with 10 characters, the remaining space gets filled with spaces.

I know that char allocates the space staticly, but does that also mean that I get a string in the format like "abc               " ?

Since this make sql statements with equal operators difficult.

Comment: `varchar` not `char` (that is fixed size)

Comment: It's best to [avoid char entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165653/230471). There's no good reason to use it.

Comment: Also, [don't use varchar either](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-DF7E10FC-A461-4325-A295-3FD4D150809E). The standard string type in Oracle is `varchar2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are operating under a misconception; it has nothing to do with SQL Developer.

A `CHAR` data-type is a fixed-length string; if you do not provide a string of the full length then Oracle will right-pad the string with space (ASCII 32) characters until it has the correct length.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1821):

> ## `CHAR` Datatype
>
> The `CHAR` datatype stores fixed-length character strings. When you create a table with a `CHAR` column, you must specify a string length (in bytes or characters) between 1 and 2000 bytes for the `CHAR` column width. The default is 1 byte. Oracle then guarantees that:
>
> - When you insert or update a row in the table, the value for the `CHAR` column has the fixed length.
> - If you give a shorter value, then the value is blank-padded to the fixed length.
> - If a value is too large, Oracle Database returns an error.
>
> Oracle Database compares `CHAR` values using blank-padded comparison semantics.

To solve this, do not use `CHAR` for variable length strings and use `VARCHAR2` instead.

> ## `VARCHAR2` and `VARCHAR` Datatypes
>
> The `VARCHAR2` datatype stores variable-length character strings. When you create a table with a `VARCHAR2` column, you specify a maximum string length (in bytes or characters) between 1 and 4000 bytes for the `VARCHAR2` column. For each row, Oracle Database stores each value in the column as a variable-length field unless a value exceeds the column's maximum length, in which case Oracle Database returns an error. Using `VARCHAR2` and `VARCHAR` saves on space used by the table.

Comment: SO I should always use VARCHAR2 and if I know for sure the length of all entries is the same I could use char for better performance?

Answer (score 3):

You may use **varchar2** instead of **char** as datatype to avoid this.

Or you can trim your data in query by using **rtrim(columnname)** .

Comment: SO I should always use VARCHAR2 and if I know for sure the length of all entries is the same I could use char for better performance?

Comment: Yes you should only use CHAR if all of the records are of same size. Hope your problem has been resolved. If you need to retrieve data from any CHAR field and you don't know for sure whether their size varies or not you can trim all the blank spaces from the right side with RTRIM() or RPAD().