# Can't find the solution to an error ORA-02270

Tags: sql, oracle, schema, erd, relational

[image]

I want to convert ERD schema to relational schema. I wrote some commands, but some of them do not work.

When I try to execute this command:

```
CREATE TABLE Egzemplarz_papierowy(
id_egzemplarza INTEGER NOT NULL, 
id_autora INTEGER REFERENCES Autor(id_autora), 
tytuł CHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Książka(tytuł), 
PRIMARY KEY(id_egzemplarza, id_autora, tytuł), 
nazwa_działu CHAR(20) REFERENCES Dział(nazwa_działu), 
rok_wydania INTEGER NOT NULL,
status_wypożyczenia CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
okładka CHAR(20) NULL, 
liczba_stron INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

an error occurs: ORA-02270. I understand that it is telling me that there is a mismatch in PRIMARY KEYS, but I don't understand why, because primary keys of entity Książka are matched and I am only adding id_egzemplarza here. What should I do?

Whole code:

```
CREATE TABLE Autor(id_autora INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, imię CHAR(20) NOT NULL, nazwisko CHAR(20) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Dział(nazwa_działu CHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, liczba_egzemplarzy INTEGER NOT NULL, liczba_egzemplarzy_wypożyczonych INTEGER NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Książka(tytuł CHAR(20) NOT NULL, id_autora INTEGER REFERENCES Autor(id_autora), nazwa_działu CHAR(20) REFERENCES Dział(nazwa_działu), PRIMARY KEY(tytuł, id_autora), liczba_egzemplarzy INTEGER NOT NULL, liczba_egzemplarzy_wypożyczonych INTEGER NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Egzemplarz_papierowy(id_egzemplarza INTEGER NOT NULL, id_autora INTEGER REFERENCES Autor(id_autora), tytuł CHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Książka(tytuł), PRIMARY KEY(id_egzemplarza, id_autora, tytuł), nazwa_działu CHAR(20) REFERENCES Dział(nazwa_działu), rok_wydania INTEGER NOT NULL, status_wypożyczenia CHAR(20) NOT NULL, okładka CHAR(20) NULL, liczba_stron INTEGER NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Egzemplarz_elektroniczny(id_egzemplarza INTEGER NOT NULL, id_autora INTEGER REFERENCES Autor(id_autora), tytuł CHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Książka(tytuł), PRIMARY KEY(id_egzemplarza, id_autora, tytuł), rok_wydania INTEGER NOT NULL, status_wypożyczenia CHAR(20) NOT NULL, okładka CHAR(20) NULL, format_pliku CHAR(20) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Karta_użytkownika(PESEL VARCHAR(11) PRIMARY KEY, imię CHAR(20) NOT NULL, nazwisko CHAR(20) NOT NULL, balans_konta INTEGER NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Należy(id_autora INTEGER REFERENCES Autor(id_autora), nazwa_działu CHAR(20) REFERENCES Dział(nazwa_działu), PRIMARY KEY(id_autora, nazwa_działu));

CREATE TABLE Wypożyczenie_papierowy(data_wypożyczenia DATE NOT NULL, id_autora REFERENCES Autor(id_autora), tytuł REFERENCES Książka(tytuł), id_egzemplarza REFERENCES Egzemplarz_papierowy(id_egzemplarza), pesel REFERENCES Karta_użytkownika(PESEL), PRIMARY KEY(data_wypożyczenia, id_autora, tytuł, pesel), rzeczywista_data_zwrotu DATE, deadline_daty_zwrotu DATE, status_wypożyczenia CHAR(20));

CREATE TABLE Wypożyczenie_elektroniczny(data_wypożyczenia DATE NOT NULL, id_autora REFERENCES Autor(id_autora), tytuł REFERENCES Książka(tytuł), id_egzemplarza REFERENCES Egzemplarz_elektroniczny(id_egzemplarza), pesel REFERENCES Karta_użytkownika(PESEL), PRIMARY KEY(data_wypożyczenia, id_autora, tytuł, pesel), rzeczywista_data_zwrotu DATE, deadline_daty_zwrotu DATE, status_wypożyczenia CHAR(20));
```

Answer (score 1):

A multi-column constraint can't be defined as part of one column - it has to be a separate definition. So this:

```
tytuł CHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Książka(tytuł)
```

won't work, because the PK of Książka is

```
CREATE TABLE Książka( ... PRIMARY KEY(tytuł, id_autora) );
```

The FK referencing it needs to name both columns, like this:

```
foreign key (tytuł, id_autora) references książka(tytuł, id_autora)
```

Fixed script (first four tables):

```
create table autor
( id_autora                         integer primary key
, imię                              varchar2(20) not null
, nazwisko                          varchar2(20) not null );

create table dział
( nazwa_działu                      varchar2(20) primary key
, liczba_egzemplarzy                integer not null
, liczba_egzemplarzy_wypożyczonych  integer not null);

create table książka
( tytuł                             varchar2(20) not null
, id_autora                         references autor(id_autora)
, nazwa_działu                      references dział(nazwa_działu)
, liczba_egzemplarzy                integer not null
, liczba_egzemplarzy_wypożyczonych  integer not null
, primary key(tytuł, id_autora)
);

create table egzemplarz_papierowy
( id_egzemplarza                    integer not null
, id_autora                         references autor(id_autora)
, tytuł                             varchar2(20) not null
, nazwa_działu                      references dział(nazwa_działu)
, rok_wydania                       integer not null
, status_wypożyczenia               varchar2(20) not null
, okładka                           varchar2(20) null
, liczba_stron                      integer not null
, primary key(id_egzemplarza, id_autora, tytuł)
, foreign key (tytuł, id_autora) references książka(tytuł, id_autora)
);
```

You might consider naming the constraints, as then any violation errors will be easier to trace, although I do sometimes wish they would find a way to word the error message in a way that doesn't require a named constraint, as with `not null`.

You should [avoid `CHAR`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165653/230471), as it's a bug trap with no advantages, designed (I can only imagine) for ANSI completeness and cross-platform portability, rather than any useful functionality, as it has none.

For single-column foreign key constraints, you can omit the datatype and let it inherit from the parent table, which in my view is better practice.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for defining a PK in Oracle is:

```
CONSTRAINT constraint_name PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
```

Comment: This is a valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be with the definition of table Książka which has composite Primary key containing the columns tytuł, id_autora but when you are creating the foreign key you have referred to only column `tytuł`.

You should change your create table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE Egzemplarz_papierowy(
id_egzemplarza INTEGER NOT NULL, 
id_autora INTEGER REFERENCES Autor(id_autora), 
tytuł CHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Książka(tytuł, id_autora), 
PRIMARY KEY(id_egzemplarza, id_autora, tytuł), 
nazwa_działu CHAR(20) REFERENCES Dział(nazwa_działu), 
rok_wydania INTEGER NOT NULL,
status_wypożyczenia CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
okładka CHAR(20) NULL, 
liczba_stron INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are problems in the definitions of keys on the `Egzemplarz_papierowy`, `Egzemplarz_elektroniczny`, `Wypożyczenie_papierowy`, and `Wypożyczenie_elektroniczny` tables. In each of these tables an attempt is made to create a foreign key constraint on a single field - however, the primary key on the target table is a multiple-column key. For example, your definition of `Egzemplarz_papierowy` is:

```
CREATE TABLE Egzemplarz_papierowy(
id_egzemplarza INTEGER NOT NULL, 
id_autora INTEGER REFERENCES Autor(id_autora), 
tytuł CHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Książka(tytuł), 
PRIMARY KEY(id_egzemplarza, id_autora, tytuł), 
nazwa_działu CHAR(20) REFERENCES Dział(nazwa_działu), 
rok_wydania INTEGER NOT NULL,
status_wypożyczenia CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
okładka CHAR(20) NULL, 
liczba_stron INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

This fails because of the REFERENCES clause on the `tytuł` field:

```
tytuł CHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Książka(tytuł),
```

as the field `tytuł` is neither a primary or unique key on the table `Książka`. Foreign keys must refer to *all* of the fields on the target table which are in either a primary key or unique key constraint.

To correct this you should change the foreign key constraint to include all the columns which are in the primary key of the `Książka` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Egzemplarz_papierowy
 (id_egzemplarza INTEGER
   NOT NULL,
  id_autora INTEGER
    REFERENCES Autor(id_autora),
  tytuł CHAR(20)
    NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (tytuł, id_autora)
    REFERENCES Książka(tytuł, id_autora),
  PRIMARY KEY(id_egzemplarza, id_autora, tytuł),
  nazwa_działu CHAR(20)
    REFERENCES Dział(nazwa_działu),
  rok_wydania INTEGER
    NOT NULL,
  status_wypożyczenia CHAR(20)
    NOT NULL,
  okładka CHAR(20)
    NULL,
  liczba_stron INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

This compiles correctly. The `Egzemplarz_elektroniczny`, `Wypożyczenie_papierowy`, and `Wypożyczenie_elektroniczny` tables have similar problems.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b0b57ed72902b67dd844995226b80de8)