# Criteria on char(1) field

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle,

In a table, I have a field char(1). Field value are 0, 1 or empty
field are empty

so i tried to do

```sql
select p.id, p.confidential_phone
from person p
where p.confidential_phone=''
```

No result are retourned

I tried with
`= ' '`
`is null`

same result

Comment: If `is null` does not work it is possible, that you have some whitespace characters like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/NVH7XCOl)?.

Comment: Just to mention, setting a `char` column to `''` in SQL is different to assigning `a := ''` in PL/SQL. Yet another reason to [avoid `char`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165653/230471). Why not use the standard `varchar2`?

Answer (score 2):

`''` in oracle is `NULL`. Never do `= ''`, use `IS NULL` instead.

Your query should work like this:

```sql
select p.id, p.confidential_phone
from person p
where p.confidential_phone is null
```

Consider this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/05ks4w-7)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle teats empty strings as NULL, so IS  NULL will work

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id int, confidential_phone char(1))
```

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1,'1')
```

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2,'0')
```

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (3,'')
```

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (4,NULL)
```

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE confidential_phone IS NULL
```

| ID | CONFIDENTIAL_PHONE |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | *null* |
| 4 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Lq6DjrMD)